# Visual Studio DEBUG menu disabled

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I'm trying out VS 2017 Community Edition*.

When I open a plain .HTML for .JS file the Debug > Start Debugging and Start without Debugging are disabled.

[image]

I've tried attaching the Internet Explorer Process. I can then Debug > Start  but the page doesn't appear in Internet Explorer.

I must be missing something super obvious, but I'm completely new to VS for web development.

- Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017 
  Version 15.8.2

Comment: Can I get a hint as to why the downvote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Project ( File > New > Project) and then add the .aspx file to the project.
Should be able to debug then.